# Where to find Scheme library functions?

Tags: scheme

Is there a reference website to look up syntax for Scheme library function like http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/?

I'm looking for syntax of `fold`, but google gave me nothing :(

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`fold`](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-1/srfi-1.html#fold) is from [SRFI 1](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-1/srfi-1.html). Many functions have good documentation if you know where it "comes from".

Also, since you're using Racket (as mentioned in your previous questions), you should check out the [Racket documentation](http://docs.racket-lang.org). It has a very nice search facility. (Also, you might like to know about Racket's [`foldl`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket/private/base..rkt%29._foldl%29%29), which is identical to SRFI 1's `fold`.)

Comment: Thanks! I'm trying to `fold` in Scheme now :P!

Comment: @Chan: Congrats! I hope you enjoy your `fold`ing adventures. :-)

Comment: Thanks for the complement. After playing around with Scheme a bit, I realized trying use imperative language idea don't always work, sometimes it's even much harder than Scheme's way. So I guess I need to adapt myself.